# docker login to hosted repository nexus failed

Tags: docker, nginx, nexus, docker-registry, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to  connect to a private repository, in my case it's nexus, in order to push some Docker images. After setting up the repository on nexus, nginx config file, and the self-signed certificate using `keytool`, I still have the error shown below. I'm currently working in a corporate network that uses a proxy, could it be the issue ? 
Thank you in advance

```
docker login -u admin repo.nexusidemia.com:48085
Error response from daemon: Get http://repo.nexusidemia.com:48085/v2/: EOF

OR

Error response from daemon: Get http://repo.nexusidemia.com:48085/v2/:
 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:48085: connect: connection refused
```

nginx configuration:

```
events { worker_connections 768; # multi_accept on; }
     http 
    { proxy_send_timeout 120;
 proxy_read_timeout 300; proxy_buffering    off
; keepalive_timeout  5 5;
 tcp_nodelay        on;
     server 
{ listen 48085 ssl; 
server_name repo.nexusidemia.com; 
ssl_certificate nexusidemia.cert; 
ssl_certificate_key  nexusidemia.key;
 ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
 location / { 
proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
 proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_redirect          http:// https://; 
proxy_pass              http://repo.nexusidemia.com:8085;
 client_max_body_size       1024m;
 client_body_buffer_size    128k; } 
}
```

Nexus Configuration
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFMe3.png

When I try to access the URL `https://repo.nexusidemia.com:48085` I get the secure lock with an error message.

```
HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing /. Reason:
not a docker request
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD5Dj.png

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should include the last error message as text in the question instead of only posting an image of it.

Comment: i think now it's all good.